# Is there any method by which I can send random key events to an X11 application?

Tags: linux, xorg

So I'm writing a game, and I'm getting crashes very intermittently occuring on movement. I'm trying to get a backtrace out of `gdb`, but it's incredibly tedious to keep bumbling around, hoping to hit the bug. I want an application that will send random keyboard events (preferably a subset chosen by me) to an X application (an SDL window in this case).

I tried googling and searching SuperUser, but if such an application exists (as I am sure there is) the keywords I'm using aren't hitting it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/). It's a simple command-line program that can send various events (including key-presses) to X11.

Simply write a little script in the language of your choice to call

```
xdotool key [key to press]
```

You can also do separate keydown and keyup events, so you can simulate a user holding down a key.

Answer (score 2):

`xwit` is another scripting tool that allows sending / setting various X11 events.  `xwininfo` is useful for gathering information (such as what window you're specifically interested in), and `xmctrl` allows scripting some X window manager actions as well.